# Samsung np530u3c (5 series) not booting and can't access the BIOS

Tags: laptop, bios, uefi

I have this computer that I've been using with manjaro. Today I decided to replace the thermalpaste, everything went smooth, but when I tried to turn it on, it would restart and go to an empty "boot menu", even though I have the hdd and a live usb connected. Also I can't access the BIOS, I'm spamming the F2 key even with an usb keyboard and nothing, it goes to the "boot menu" thing. 
Here's a video of this behaviour:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WmFvG9RKP_k

Things I've tried:
-booting from a legacy and an UEFI live usb (boot menu doesn't recognize the pendrives)
-Removing the CMOS battery

So, I'm out of ideas, and given I'm in lock-down beacuse of the covid I can't take it to a technician, it sucks because I need it for college.
If you could help me I'd be really thankful.
Thank you and stay safe!

Answer (score 0):

So, it's been a long time after I posted this. I managed to get the computer working again, not by myself though. I sent it to get the BIOS reflashed, it's the easiest way to fix this. If you have this problem there are a few things you can try before.
Spam the F9 key to access an usb live windows (also called "windows to go") or try to boot from an usb-hdd with a windows installed in it. Then proceed to download the Samsung Bios update tool and run it. If you're lucky enough your computer will fix itself, otherwise take it to a good tech shop (or samsung) to get it re-flashed (it's ussually cheap).
This issue is common on this Samsungs with the UEFI Phoenix bios activated, so avoid using that. Good luck.